# Matching list name with function input

Tags: r, list

I have defined two global variables as lists, let's say:

```
importance.5maturity <- list()
importance.10maturity <- list()
```

I also have a function which runs `randomForest` and I want to add the `Importance` of this function in the list, in each loop (I am using a rolling window). I believe this can be done using `list.append()`.
The input of this function has a variable named `maturity`. I want to have an `if` statement, in a way that if the list name in global variable has the same number as in `maturity`, the function stores the `Importance` information in that particular list. For example,

```
b <- randomForest(y ~., data= d.na, mtry=5, ntree=1000, importance=TRUE)
if(maturity==5){
importance.5maturity <- list.append(Importance(b))
```

But I don't know how to match the `maturity` and the number  (5 and 10) in the list name so the function would choose the correct list to store the information in automatically.
I also don't want to use local variables, which the function would return, since I am returning another data frame from it.

Comment: well one problem is in your if statement, you are missing the double ==

Comment: Thanks @D.J. This is just a demo to illustrate what I want to do.

Comment: How many values does maturity have? If only two (5/10) the you could have an if-else loop set up such that if it's 5 then you drop into editing that list and if it's 10 then you edit the 10maturity list. If you have lots of values, then an alternative approach might be to have a single master list/df that stores all the importance information for all maturities and then you can pull those out.